# Animated displacement of rigid body does not collide with other rigid bodies

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, displacement

I am playing with rigid bodies in 2.79 and I'm having the following problem.

I have subdivided a plane a few times, then added subsurface and displace modifiers. I animated
the displacement with a cloud texture and an animated null.
A rigid body physic was also added to the plane (with 'passive', 'animated', 'mesh', and 'deforming' selected).

This creates an animated pseudo ocean surface.

I then add a few icospheres in the scene, on top of the plane. They are simply active rigid bodies.

When I do the Free Bake of the Rigid Bodies, the Icospheres instead of interacting with the animated 
and displaced plane, they simply rest on the original flat plane.

Am I doing something wrong or displaced animated objects cannot be rigid bodies in Blender?

Many thanks for any comment and advice.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You will have to apply all the modifiers in order to achieve this

Comment: Try switching source type from *Deform* to *Final* for displaced mesh in physics settings

Comment: Just an idea. Not tested. What if you use a collision plane with Shrink Wrap on top of the displaced plane?

Answer (score 0):

many thanks for your help.

I actually did it in an indirect way, a few days ago, by using arrays of passive/animated rigid bodies and connecting them to the animated plane by using Shrink Wrap. This created a moving floor (up-down motion), that interacted with the active/rigid icospheres, giving the result I wanted. Many thanks for your help and I will try the suggested methods to see if they work too.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this easily by exporting the mesh simulation as a Newtek/Lightwave .mdd file. (Enable add-on in prefs)  Then when it is imported, it became shape keys - which seemed to work perfectly as the collision mesh.